# Como determinar uma condição de intervalo entre registros?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tratando-se de registros que contém *data e/ou hora*, como determinar que entre o primeiro registro retornado e os demais haja sempre um mesmo intervalo?  Tomemos este exemplo:

### Dados não tratados:

```
TimeStamp           | Valor

2019-01-04 14:08:07 | 29062
2019-01-04 15:09:09 | 28937
2019-01-04 15:09:10 | 28937
2019-01-04 15:09:20 | 28937
2019-01-04 15:10:21 | 28937
2019-01-04 15:40:21 | 28875
2019-01-04 16:10:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 16:40:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 17:10:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 17:40:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 18:10:21 | 28687
2019-01-04 18:40:21 | 28625
```

### Dados tratados:

```
TimeStamp           | Valor

2019-01-04 14:08:07 | 29062
2019-01-04 15:09:09 | 28937
2019-01-04 16:10:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 17:10:21 | 28812
2019-01-04 18:10:21 | 28687
```

*Considere um intervalo mínimo de 40 min*

Comment: Qual a versão do `MySQL`?

Comment: **Versão do MYSQL**: 5.6.35-81.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar variáveis para controlar qual a data que será utilizada de base.

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
  data  TIMESTAMP,
  valor INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tabela(data, valor)
            VALUES('2019-01-04 14:08:07', 29062),
                  ('2019-01-04 15:09:09', 28937),
                  ('2019-01-04 15:09:10', 28937),
                  ('2019-01-04 15:09:20', 28937),
                  ('2019-01-04 15:10:21', 28937),
                  ('2019-01-04 15:40:21', 28875),
                  ('2019-01-04 16:10:21', 28812),
                  ('2019-01-04 16:40:21', 28812),
                  ('2019-01-04 17:10:21', 28812),
                  ('2019-01-04 17:40:21', 28812),
                  ('2019-01-04 18:10:21', 28687),
                  ('2019-01-04 18:40:21', 28625);
```

---

**Query**

```
SET @data := NULL;

SELECT x.data,
       x.valor
  FROM (
    SELECT @data := CASE
                      WHEN @data IS NULL THEN t.data
                      WHEN t.data > @data + INTERVAL 40 MINUTE THEN t.data
                      ELSE @data
                    END,
           CASE @data
             WHEN t.data THEN 'S'
             ELSE 'N'
           END AS mostrar,
           t.*
      FROM tabela t
      ORDER by t.data) x
   WHERE x.mostrar = 'S'
   ORDER BY x.data;
```

---

**Resultando em:**

```
| data                | valor |
| ------------------- | ----- |
| 2019-01-04 14:08:07 | 29062 |
| 2019-01-04 15:09:09 | 28937 |
| 2019-01-04 16:10:21 | 28812 |
| 2019-01-04 17:10:21 | 28812 |
| 2019-01-04 18:10:21 | 28687 |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/92jXXyfC9JBzcTBvRLSHQ/1).